# How to search a value from array of objects in DynamoDB in node js

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

For suppose the item is like

```
{
'EventType': 'git/push'
'EventTime': 1416251010,
'Commits': [
    {
        'id': '29d02aff...',
        'subject': 'Add the thing to the place'
    },
    {
        'id': '9d888fec...',
        'subject': 'Spelling errors'
    },
    ...
]
```

}

then I want the output like

```
{
'EventType': 'git/push'
'EventTime': 1416251010,
'Commits': [
    {
        'id': '29d02aff...',
        'subject': 'Add the thing to the place'
    }
 ]
}
```

can you please suggest me the DynamoDB filter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are the attributes you would like to search with ?

Comment: Thanks notionquest for responding this post, I want to filter with _EventType_ and _subject_ from comments, actually, comments will contain more than one recode with the same subject, that is the case I want all the records with the matched subject.

Comment: If you know both the id and subject of the comments, then it is possible. Otherwise, it is not possible.

Comment: ok if I know id and subject how can I apply the filter condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CONTAINS** function can be used to filter or find the data in DynamoDB list. However, please note that you need to have both the attributes (i.e. id and subject) of the object (complex object in terms of DynamoDB) to find the data in List.

> CONTAINS is supported for lists: When evaluating "a CONTAINS b", "a"
>   can be a list; however, "b" cannot be a set, a map, or a list.

**Sample code:-**

```
var table = "eventtype";
var params = {
    TableName: table,
    KeyConditionExpression: "EventType = :eventType",
    FilterExpression: "contains(Commits, :commitVal )",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":eventType": 'git/push',
        ":commitVal": {
            'id': '29d02aff',
            'subject': 'Add the thing to the place'
        }
    }
};

docClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
            null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is it possible only with id.? in some situations I'm only known id I don't know a subject.

Comment: @Ram did you find a way to just check with `id` and not `subject`? I have a similar situation. Thanks!!

Comment: @RamMohan222, is there a way to get it with just ID?